# Please clarify the term Class Static Object (vs class static member)

Tags: c++

I've run across the term **Class Static Object** a number of times without code or context to clarify if this is the author's term for something I don't know or an just another term for **class (scoped) static member (variable or function)**.

```
class m1 {
public:
    static int x;
};

// with x being the "class static "object"
// which I just call a "class static member".
int m1::x;
```

Or, does the term only apply to member variables that are actually user defined objects?

```
class m2 {
public:
    int y;
};

class m3 {
public:
    static m2 z;
};

// with z really being an object - the "class static object"?
m2 m3::z;
```

Comment: Next time ask the speaker to clarify. I don't believe that's a common term, but I'd interpret it as referring to static data member (primitive or user-defined type) as opposed to static member functions.

Comment: The most common usage I've seen of this term is effectively for a static class member of the same class type with a protected or private constructor to prevent outside construction. I normally only see it in singleton-classes ( which I'm not a fan of at all). The instructor needs to clarify with an example.

Comment: Mat/Craig - There is no "speaker" or "instructor" to ask.  I mentioned "author" in my post to refer to a number of different articles (including slide presentations) where there is no opportunity to ask, comment or otherwise interact.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider both cases to be referring to "Class Static Objects". An object is simply an entity which occupies memory that is not a function, so it does not matter whether it is a user-defined type (UDT) or not.

As for the difference between "class static member", functions can also be "members", so I would say the difference is that "Class Static Object" does not include functions.

Personally, I would use "static member variables" and "static member functions", rather than that terminology.